# Issue with Geonear in latest mongo c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

have a .NET Application that uses a MongoDB so I am using mongo c# driver. Current version I am using is 1.9.2.

I am trying to update this to latest C# mongodb driver - 2.7.0. I have had to make numerous code changes so far for breaking changes.  I am having an issue getting the below to work

**1.9.2 Driver Code:**

```
public IQueryable<Tuple<Location, double>> GeoNear(StagedLocation stagedLocation, int matchRadius)
{

    var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(stagedLocation.Address.Longitude.Value, stagedLocation.Address.Latitude.Value)); //long, lat 

    var results = collection.GeoNear(new GeoNearArgs { Spherical = true, Near = point, MaxDistance = matchRadius, Limit = 20});

    return results.Hits.Select(loc => Tuple.Create(loc.Document, loc.Distance)).AsQueryable();
}
```

I am trying to do the same thing in the 2.7.0 version of the Driver but the code below is not working:

**2.7.0 Driver Code:**

```
    public IQueryable<Tuple<Location, double>> GeoNear(StagedLocation stagedLocation, int matchRadius)
    {
        var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(stagedLocation.Address.Longitude.Value, stagedLocation.Address.Latitude.Value)); //long, lat          

        var test = collection.FindAsync<Location>(Builders<Location>.Filter.Near(l => l, point, matchRadius, 0));

        return test.Result.ToList().Select(loc => Tuple.Create(loc, 0.0)).AsQueryable();
    }
```

However this is throwing the error:

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for l => l.
```

Not sure if the 2.7.0 code I have put in place is even the correct way of doing the same GeoNear as was working in 1.9.2 version

Update Location class included

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Location : EntityBase, IEquatable<Location>
    {
        public int VersionNumber { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Address class also marked as serilizable .  Entitybase class below:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTimeOffset LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste `Location` class ?

Comment: @mickl - Location class included - just not sure if that is even the correct way to attempt geonear in the latest driver so the serilization error might be a red herring

Comment: @mickl - did adding the Location class help anyt